# functional analysis- prove that $T$ is a topological isomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis

> -Let $X;Y$ are Banach spaces and a continuous linear map $T:X \rightarrow Y$;such that:Y is the closure of Im(T) and there exists a positive number $\alpha$ satisfying $||Tx|| \geq \alpha ||x|| \forall x \in X$.prove that:$T$ is a topological isomorphism.

I proved that $T$ is a surjection but I don't know why it is a injection.Can someone help me? thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Vert Tx - Ty \Vert \ge \alpha \Vert x - y \Vert > 0$$ for $x \neq y$.

Comment: @drhab- yes;$T$ is linear.I forget that.thanks.